# Understanding how super works

Tags: python, python-2.7

given below python program .

```
class FooBase(object):
   def foo(self): pass

class A(FooBase):
    def foo(self):
        super(A, self).foo()
        print 'A.foo()'

class B(FooBase):
    def foo(self):
        super(B, self).foo()
        print 'B.foo()'

class D(B):
    def foo(self):
        super(D, self).foo()
        print 'D.foo()'


class C(A,D,B):
    def foo(self):
        super(C, self).foo()
        print 'C.foo()'

c=C()
c.foo()
```

output is

```
B.foo()
D.foo()
A.foo()
C.foo()
```

but when i ran below program

```
class A1(object):
    def get(self):
        print 'A1'
class A2(object):
    def get(self):
        print 'A2'
class A3(object):
    def get(self):
        print 'A3'
class B2(A2):
    def get(self):
        super(B2,self).get()
        print 'b2'
class B3(A3):
    def get(self):
        super(B3,self).get()
        print 'b3'
class C3(B3):
    def get(self):
        super(C3,self).get()
        print 'c3'
class Foo(C3, A1, B2):
    def get(self):
        super(Foo,self).get()
        print 'Foo'



#print Foo.__mro__
Foo().get()
```

when i excuted the above i got the output as below

output

```
A3
b3
c3
Foo
```

the question why does the `A1.get()` and `B2.get()` was not called.is there any wrong with the calling of super?

i was expecting the output

```
A3
b3
c3
A1
A2
b2
Foo
```

**Edit**: if anyone explain what is difference between first and second example would be great:)

Comment: @jonrsharpe this might be different from that. i already got three reopen votes.please reopen and i am seeking better answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are defining a new style class, subclassing from multiple classes ([multiple inheritance](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#multiple-inheritance)). As such,

> For old-style classes, the only rule is depth-first, left-to-right. Thus, if an attribute is not found in DerivedClassName, it is searched in Base1, then (recursively) in the base classes of Base1, and only if it is not found there, it is searched in Base2, and so on.
>
> With new-style classes, dynamic ordering is necessary because all cases of multiple inheritance exhibit one or more diamond relationships (where at least one of the parent classes can be accessed through multiple paths from the bottommost class). For example, all new-style classes inherit from object, so any case of multiple inheritance provides more than one path to reach object. To keep the base classes from being accessed more than once, the dynamic algorithm linearizes the search order in a way that preserves the left-to-right ordering specified in each class

Thus, in the linear ordering, only `C3.get` is called, which in turn calls `B3.get`, and which calls `A3.get`

---

If you want to print the `get` methods from other classes as well, use the following `Foo` class:

```
class Foo(C3, A1, B2):
    def get(self):
        print '='*20 + 'Foo'
        super(Foo, self).get()
        print '='*20 + 'A1'
        super(A1, self).get()
        print '='*20 + 'B2'
        super(B2, self).get()
```

Then, the code on running should output the right text

```
$ python file.py 
====================Foo
A3
b3
c3
====================A1
A2
b2
====================B2
A2
```

Comment: how can i call A1 and b2 get?how does python know which style to use. first example all the class were called and in second example only some .

Comment: The problem is that `A1`, `A2`, and `A3` do not call `super` in their implementations of `get`, breaking the chain of calls. To fix, they need to do so, as well as inheriting from a *single* base class (such as `_getroot`) which implements `get` without calling `super`, so that you don't end up trying to call the nonexistent `object.get`.

Comment: @sundarnatarajСундар Check edits

Comment: when you called A1 how come b2 has come there?

Comment: `super` does not invoke the parent's method. Rather, each class has a fixed ordering of all its ancestor classes, and `super(A1, self)` returns a proxy for the next class in the order for `type(self)`, which is not necessarily the parent (or a parent) of `A1`.

Comment: You can see the method resolution order for the class `Foo` by examining the tuple `Foo.__mro__`. It is (roughly) obtained by doing a depth-first search of the inheritance tree rooted at `Foo`.

Comment: ```>>> Foo.mro()
[<class '__main__.Foo'>, <class '__main__.C3'>, <class '__main__.B3'>, <class '__main__.A3'>, <class '__main__.A1'>, <class '__main__.B2'>, <class '__main__.A2'>, <type 'object'>]```

Comment: please comment to question rather than answer.:)

Comment: @chepner how does first example differ from second

Comment: In the first example, every class that calls `foo` ultimately inherits from `FooBase`. In the second, classes that provide `get` have three distinct "base" classes `A1`, `A2`, and `A3`, which independently "invent" `get`, rather than inheriting from a single ancestor.

Comment: @chepner thank you i got it. so if there is no proper ancestors.it rather go from left to right in multiple in heritance. if proper ancestors it do right to left .thats correct

Comment: See [this page](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) for details on how the order is computed. It includes a link to the original paper that defined the C3 resolution order for the programming language Dylan (which uses the much better name `next-method` for its version of `super`).